# How to join the NCR in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Iv'e been playing Fallout New Vegas and I haven't gotten very far but I was wondering how I could join the NCR. I really want to join this faction. Is there any specific place to go or any specific person that I have to meet in order to join the NCR? Also, what are the requirements (if there is any) to join so that I can be prepared for in the future.

Comment: Kill them all. They suck hard, and force you to do silly quests. They're an endless supply of medium armor and service rifles for jury rig repair, though. Also, NCR ranger assassins are trivial compared to legion assassins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the NCR MUST come to you.  After exiting the Lucky 38 after complete the quest "Ring-a-Ding-Ding"  After that go to Camp Maclaron and talk to the Bounty hunter and ask where he got the Caps and he will say about the Major. After doing so talk to the Major and ask if you can do a bounty. Choose from the three but be careful about the last choice of the three save that one for last (My personal choice) because of the difficulty. First and the most easist and you can find the second bounty but at the same time it is second to most difficult.  After that the last bounty you can have the sniper squaddren to help you kill the target and you get two or five rewards (depending if you want the weapons dropped by the other two bounties) The first reward for helping the NCR is a two way radio and the second big reward is the weapon of the third bounty which is a unique weapon if you want to use a melee weapon. But DON'T KILL ANY NCR SOLDIERS!

Comment: You don't need to do those bounties to join the NCR.

Answer (score 16):

Play the main storyline until you reach New Vegas and get to Mr. House's Casino. If you exit the house, you'll get approached by an NCR soldier. he'll send you to the embassy, where the NCR storyline begins.

source: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/959557-fallout-new-vegas/56897584

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the info. I think I actually remember getting approached by  an NCR member but I didn't continue on that mission.

Comment: @NuclearTiger52 if an answer solved your issue, a good idea is to accept it so other people also know this. It also gives both the asker and answerer some reputation. I suggest you accept Ohnana's answer though, since his answer is more detailed.

Comment: his answer was a little more rude so were going with yours =)

Comment: This is the way to get the main NCR quest line going, but you can do quests for them before this. The first time you're likely to run into NCR soldiers is south of Primm. If you have some NCR reputation (which you probably don't yet) they'll give a mission related to the powder gangers. You can get some NCR rep by doing quests at the Mojave Outpost, which you run into soon after. It's in the southeast corner of the map. You can get a service rifle as a reward, which is a nice gun early on.

Answer (score 5):

Requirements: Do not murder NCR troops (duh). Doesn't matter if you murder the legion, that's irrelevant. Doing quests for the legion or the Powder Gangers will make the NCR unhappy. Try not to get too far into the main quest, else you might miss your chance.

After the quest "Ring-A-Ding-Ding," you will be approached by an NCR soldier. They will ask you to go to the NCR embassy, where you can begin helping. Side note: being friends with a group called the Boomers will make this quest bug out a bit. If you don't know who they are, that's fine. Don't go walking through minefields.

To build reputation, you can go to Camp McCarran, Sloan, and Camp Forlorn Hope for related quests.

Comment: Here's the thing, you can actually do as much bad shit as you want as long as you do it *before* the NCR  comes up to you after Ring-a-Ding-Ding, even going as far as utterly decimating Camp Mccarran.
The NCR will offer you a full pardon, even before you start any quests for them
The same deal is on the table for the legion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually join them. You can unlock their safe house and be idolized and stuff, but you can't join them.

Answer (score 0):

in the storyline, if you get popular with the NCR they will send someone to you after you leave the lucky 38. you need a good NCR rep BEFORE entering the lucky 38 for this.